# Is it possible to get a value from a JavaScript immediately-invoked arrow function by using a "return" statement?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

In this code example:

```
let result = (async (global) => {
  // other code here (includes await's; thus the async)
  return 123;
})(this);
```

The code works, but the return'ed value is nowhere to be found (not in `result`). Is there any way to use a normal return statement to get data out of this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have used an async function it returns a promise instead of a value.

Try the following:

```js
var result = (async (global) => {
  // other code here (includes await's; thus the async)
  return 123;
})(this);

result.then((res)=> console.log(res));
```

Comment: Yes, good point. I did also try a version with `var resulit = await (async...`, but this threw an exception. I'll play around with both the await and the .then approach a bit more.

Comment: @eric You can't use await outside an async function, so you would need that whole statement to be inside a function declared `async` to use it. You can use Promise#then anywhere though.

Comment: Understood. The code you see is actually inside another `async` function; omitted here for brevity. I ultimately got it to work using await. This was one of those cases where I tried a dozen different things and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @eric Awesome to hear you were able to get it working :)